# How do I implement logging on a per-thread basis?

Tags: python, logging, python-multithreading

I want to get the logs from an individual thread into a specific file that only contains logs from that thread.

In most cases, it would be totally satisfactory to just log from all threads into a single file. This will not work for me. I am applying a concurrent model to a large and currently iterative code base that has logging implemented all over the place in different modules, and I am trying to change as little code as possible.

I can think of several solutions that just seem a bit hacky that involve detecting if the current code is executing in a thread, so I am wondering if there is a nice Pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Are you able to format your logger to add the thread id? If you do this you can filter out on that in the logs themselves using grep if you want to minimize code changes to the main application.

Comment: absolutely, but lets say the thread calls 5 different functions from 5 different modules, and I want those functions to end up in the thread log, how will those functions log to the same logger with the special formatter / handler?

Comment: Look at the answer that was just posted. That is your ideal approach with the least code change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're already using the `logging` module, its very easy. You should have something like this:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('mylog.log')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
log.addHandler(file_handler)

log.debug('this is awesome!')
```

well go to your `logging.Formatter` and add `%(thread)d` and `%(threadName)s` and presto! You have a thread aware logger!

so again, it will look like this:

```
logging.Formatter('%(thread)d - %(threadName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
```

then.. `grep` it. Voila! No need to change anything else.

Here are all of them if you're interested: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes

Comment: Thanks! this is news to me, although it still doesn't completely solve my problem. (still a great help though)

Logically, we can pretend each thread is printing a separate magazine article line by line, so it would be impossible to read any of the articles all together. 

In order to get them into separate files I would have to parse based on the thread name, which isn't 100% ideal for my circumstance, partially because I am actually using worker threads, so 1 thread might process 3 'articles'.

Also, i can change some of our system wide logging, just not if I am hacking it.

Comment: I could also change the thread name on a per work item basis, but this is hackish, and wouldn't allow me any level of control

Comment: You can add that add a new `logging.FileHandler` for every thread and change the name like that, but that would require you to change things around a bit. And add a little more code, but at the end you will have a X files with the output of each thread in it..

Comment: I can give you an example, but i would need to see how you're using your threads. You need to post a little code buddy ;)

Comment: Too much code to add, and if I did it would just make it more confusing, I am going to add a new type of handler that essentially detects if we are using a thread, and creates or uses a stream to a file just for that thread. Kind of like having a list of file handlers. Thanks for the pointers man!

Comment: This is excellent - it would be helpful to note that this is a built-in logging function (not a custom format) that derives from the `thread.name` property.  Thanks!